# wp_mail (Wordpress mail function) not sending to gmail or live.co.uk accounts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, email

I have a website that allows visitors to contact me two ways - via a contact form on it's own page and via an 'ajax' small contact form in the sidebar.

Both forms of contact send an email to my gmail account.

The contact form on it's own page works fine but the ajax form doesn't send to gmail (nor does it send to email addresses ending in .live.co.uk)

If I change the 'to' address on the ajax contact form to one of my other domains (i.e. a different email address) then it works fine.

I've checked the headers of the emails that are sent and ended up installing a 'plugin' that alters the return-path in case Google (and live.co.uk) check this before accepting emails. This hasn't made any difference.

There is a lot of chatter on these forums and others about wp_mail not sending to gmail but no actual solution.

I've checked the gmail spam folders etc in case the emails went in there but they are not.

I've also tried using just the 'mail()' function but to no avail.

My code on the page that the ajax call goes to looks like this:

```
$headers  = 'From: myWebsite <enquiries@mywebsite.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: myWebsite <enquiries@mywebsite.co.uk>';
$email_to = "myemailaddy@gmail.com";
wp_mail( $email_to , sanitize_text_field( $subjectLine ), wp_strip_all_tags( $emailContent ), $headers );
$email_to = "myemailaddy@anotherdomain.com";
wp_mail( $email_to , sanitize_text_field( $subjectLine ), wp_strip_all_tags( $emailContent ), $headers );
```

Everytime the form is submitted I get the email to my 'anotherdomain.com' address but not to my gmail.com address.

Any ideas?

Comment: whats the behaviour when  gmail domain is used ? does it give any specific error code/error message  as a return value ?

Comment: What I feel like might be going on here is that your domain could've been flagged by Google and they could be just trashing/refusing the emails as soon as they see that they come from your domain. Are you sending out a lot of emails from your domain? Try using this tool - http://www.senderbase.org/ and see what is the report for your domain.

Comment: As an alternative, does your mail server support SMTP? If it does, what you can do is install this plugin - http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ and configure it(so enter your username/pass/from email/port/etc). Then send a test email. Doing so will display a debug output - at the top you'd see "The result was:" and the `bool(...)` - if it says `bool(false)` red through the debug output and that might give you a better clue at what the reason for failure might be.

Comment: Hi Nikola, thank you very much for your answer. This worked a treat. Maybe you could add it as an answer and I'll mark it up? Thanks again to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of these types of questions involve email not "sending" to certain domains.  However, it is more likely that the email is not being received.  "Not received" does not mean the same as "not sent" and this is an important distinction in troubleshooting.

If other email addresses are receiving, then it is likely that something is flagging your message at the receiving hosts that you listed.

There are things that you can do to give your email a better chance of getting through without being dumped somewhere along the way:

- Use a "from" address that is a real address.  WP default is wordpress@yourdomain.com.  This can be filtered with [wp_mail_from](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from)
- Set the "sender" as the "from" address. Some spam filters reject email as spam if these two elements of the mail header do not match. There is [a simple code snippet here that will do it](http://b.utler.co/kY).
- Sending via SMTP is the best option.  You can do this via a plugin (there are several in the wordpress.org plugin repository) or you can also [set it up yourself using the phpmailer_init action](http://www.butlerblog.com/2013/12/12/easy-smtp-email-settings-for-wordpress/).

Comment: I ended up using the wp-mail-smtp plugin and this worked. Thank you for your help. Will mark this as the answer as Nikola still not got back to me (he also suggested using a plugin) and also this answer has more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hope these will help you, forgive me if my points are not valid.

1. Disable your headers & give a try, instead of from address use
   something like wordpress@mywebsite.co.uk
2. Contact hosting provider
   & confirm your server is blacklisted by Gmail & .live.co.uk
3. Try this plugin as well
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/
4. Read this article too
   http://www.butlerblog.com/2013/09/24/troubleshooting-the-wp_mail-function/

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it might help someone, on my webhost if the `From:` and `Reply-To:` email addresses are the same then the email gets rejected. Just removing the `Reply-To:` header makes it work.