# wp_mail vs php mail()

Tags: wordpress, email, dreamhost

I'm trying to solve a problem with email being sent from a WordPress site, hosted on GoDaddy with its MX record set to a Dreamhost.com mail server.

Email addressed to the site's domain `(me@mysitesdomain.com)` will not go through, yet email to any `@gmail.com` address will go through. I'm testing this with the following script ...

```
<?php
$mailResult = false;
$from = "info@mysitesdomain.com";
$to = "me@mysitesdomain.com";
$subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
$message = "This is a test to check the wp_mail functionality.";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$mailResult = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
echo "mail result: ".$mailResult;
?>
```

For both the `me@mysitesdomain.com` and the `me@gmail.com` address, the script's result is 1 (true).

As a further test, I use a similar very simple script outside of Wordpress that uses PHP mail()...

```
<?php 
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$from = "info@mysitesdomain.com";
$to = "me@mysitesdomain.com";
$subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
$message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality.;
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

That script successfully sends to both addresses. So, PHP `mail()` works but `wp_mail()` only works for `@gmail.com` addresses. What's going on within the wp_mail class that's different PHP php `mail()`?

Comment: Real answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45291/25035

Comment: Please see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703958/wp-mail-wordpress-mail-function-not-sending-to-gmail-or-live-co-uk-accounts?rq=1